# Django Serialiizer seems to lose reference to request upon serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request

I'm sending request from views.py in context to serializers.py

As you can see in ServiceCatagorySerializer()

Views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def mainPageData(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        data = {}
        data['ServiceCatagories']=ServicesCatagorySerializer(ServicesCatagory.objects.all(),
        many=True, context={'request':request}).data
        
        data['Plans']=PlansSerializer(Plans.objects.filter(Open=True),
        many=True).data
        
        data['FrontPageFeedback']=FrontPageFeedbackSerializer(FrontPageFeedback.objects.filter(Type='Good'),
        many=True).data

        
        return Response(data)
```

and in serializers.py

```
class ServicesCatagorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = ServicesCatagory
        fields = ('id','Name','Image','Description','get_absolute_url')

    def get_Image(self, ServicesCatagory):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        image_url = ServicesCatagory.Image.url
        print()
        print()
        print()
        print(dir(request))
        print()
        print()
        print()
        return request.build_absolute_uri(image_url)
```

after that in cosole i'm getting the output of print(dir(request))

[output in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReRd3.jpg)

but
[after getting data got an error of NonType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bZlW.jpg)

i got that also in console.

Comment: Please update the question embedding the relevant console log and request error.

Answer (score 0):

Add request in serializer context like following:

```py
context = {'request': request }
FrontPageFeedbackSerializer(FrontPageFeedback.objects.filter(Type='Good'), many=True, context=context).data
```

Comment: That's true but I was getting error in ServiceCatagorySerializer() and I have added context there.